# how to return a json response based on database relationship using eloquent

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I'm quite new to Laravel. I'm figuring out to work with Eloquent.

Let's say I have 2 tables: categories and products. These two table have a one-to-many relationship. 1 category can have many products.

I would like to return a JSON response which consists of an array of categories where each category has an array of products. It should look like this:

```
[
   {"name":"Category 1", "products": [
                                        {"name":"Product 1","price":"2.50"},
                                        {"name":"Product 2","price":"2.50"}
                                     ]
   },
   {"name":"Category 2", "products": [
                                        {"name":"Product 1","price":"1.95"},
                                        {"name":"Product 2","price":"2.15"}
                                     ]
   }
]
```

**Models:**

Category.php

```
<?php

class Category extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}
```

Product.php

```
<?php

class Product extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

**Database tables:**

create_categories_table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

create_products_table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('price');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

**Controller:**

class ApiController extends BaseController {

```
public function getIndex(){

    $categories = Category::all();

    return Response::json(array('data' => $categories));
}
```

}

I know how to return all of the categories or products or only the name of a category but I cannot seem to find the solution for the example of json response I mentioned above.

If anyone knows this it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could simply do this:

```
public function getIndex(){
    $categories = Category::with('Products')->get();
    return Response::json(array('data' => $categories));
}
```

The `with()` eager loads the relationship so you get pretty much what you want.

By the way, you'll probably want to change the name of this method

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

to `category()` instead, since every product can only belong to one category.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. This is what I was asking for thanks. Small question: is there a way to not return the id, created_at and updated_at fields in the response for both category and product object? without changing the database structure of course.

Comment: You could add a ``select('field1', 'field2')->get()`` to select any number of fields, but I'm not sure how that works with ``with()``. It's possible that you need to write ``select('categories.field1')`` etc., with each field explicitly written out. Or maybe it doesn't work at all, but I think it should.

Comment: @Sven Use `$hidden` or `$visible` properties on the models to hide those fields from `toArray`/`toJson` methods.

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate the help :), I would give you +1 but I can't as I'm new at stackoverflow :p